# Linear system of inequalities (aka. validity of a polytope)

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, linear-programming, computational-complexity

Consider $U=[u_1 ... u_N]$ to be a non-singular square matrix. I am interested in range space of $U$ but with one caveat, I want to find all $a$ such that each element of $Ua$ is non-negative. In other words for all natural basis vectors $e_i$

$0\leq e_i^TUa, \forall i$

Is there a non-graphical, non-numerical approach that I can take to obtain all possible $a$ (hopefully with a polynomial complexity)?

Edit: $a$ are column vectors, to eliminate scaled solutions of an  $a$ vector a normalization condition may be assumed: i.e. $a^Ta=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$\Bbb R^N_+=\{x=(x_1,\dots, x_N)\in\Bbb R^N: x_i\ge 0\mbox{ for each }i\}=$$ $$\{\lambda_1e_1+\dots+\lambda_NeN:\lambda_i\ge 0\mbox{ for each }i\}.$$ Since the matrix $U$ is non-singular, $$U^{-1}(\Bbb R^N_+)=\{\lambda_1U^{-1}e_1+\dots+\lambda_NU^{-1}e_N:\lambda_i\ge 0\mbox{ for each }i\}.$$